# On the definition of strictly semistable sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A torsion free sheaf $E$ of rank $r$ on a smooth projective variety $X$ is called semistable (resp. stable) if for every subsheaf $F \subset E$ for which $0 < \text{rank}(F) <r$ we have $\rho(F) \leq \rho(E)$ (resp. $<$), where $\rho(F) $ denotes the reduced hilbert polynomial of $F$.

Then my question is : What is meant by "$E$ is strictly semistable"?

Does it mean that there exists atleast one subsheaf $F \subset E$ such that $0 < \text{rank}(F) <r$ we have $\rho(F) = \rho(E)$ ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Strictly semistable means that for every subsheaf $F \subset E$ for which $0 <\operatorname{rank}(F)<r$ we have $\rho(F) < \rho(E)$ [strict inequality holds].

Comment: @user45878, in that case $E$ is stable .I don't think it's same as stability. Could you mention a reference?